# Photoshop will only allow SAVE-AS

Tags: adobe-photoshop, save, jpg

For reasons I don't understand, Photoshop suddenly is giving me the SAVE-AS dialog box even though I'm just selecting SAVE (CTRL+S) or using the file/save clicks.  I assume I must have inadvertently hit some key combination but I can't figure out how to restore a simple save.

I am opening JPG files through Windows File Manager and using the Open With command and selecting Adobe Photoshop.  My editing is typically limited to cropping and some image enhancements.  I never change the image type and I'm not adding layers.

I've done this for years and I'm in the middle of editing some 1,100 photographs.  The time it takes to do a SAVE-AS, and then the subsequent question upoon closing "Do you want to save the file" even though I just saved it.  How do I return Photoshop to just SAVE an automatically overwrite the file?

Comment: You absolutely don't have any other layers (including adjustment layers etc)? Photoshop should *as long as there is only a single layer* save the JPG, if there are any other layers you have to save as a new file (I just tested changing color modes and bit depths etc too and it still saves as long as there is a single layer)

Comment: Absolutely.  There is only one layer.  I've been using Photoshop for years and never had this happen.

Comment: Very strange, I can't reproduce. What PS version?

Comment: Yes, very weird.  I'm using Photoshop CC 2017 1,1 Release,  20170425.r 252 x64.  I've tried rebooting thinking maybe it would clear soemthing up in memory but no luck.  I may have to uninstall.

Comment: You say you have only one layer, but if it has an alpha channel then that will prompt the Save As dialog since JPEGs don't support transparency.  Try flattening all layers, even if you have only one. That will remove the alpha channel - of course it will also remove any transparency!

Comment: One layer OK, but is "background layer"? In other words, is your image flattened? If so, you might also want to check your channels. A saved selection creates a new channel, which can't be saved in a JPG. Finally, here's my best guess: You accidentally hit the Mask Mode hotkey (Q on my system). Since you had nothing selected, nothing seems to change but... if you check Channels Panel, you'll see the Mask Channel. Just toggle to normal mode and your gone. I place a (small) bet on this guess ^^

Comment: Thank you for the fast response.  I tried your suggestion to flatten the image and yes, that works but that brings up 2 issues; why is this suddenly happening?  I've been editing some 1,100 pictures and was more than half-way thru and this was never an issue until now and (2) if I flatten the image and make another image adustment, it has to be re-flattened again.  A solution I've found is to select the "Delete Cropped Pixels tic box in the Crop Tool.  Perhaps I clicked that inadvertently before???  Not sure but this seems to correct the problem.  Thank you again for your support.

Comment: @Midwestden If you deselect that option, the content you crop out is not deleted, only masked out from the artboard. Since JPG does not support content outside the artboard, you cannot save the resulting file as a JPG file without loss of information, and Photoshop will therefore only save a _copy_ of the file as JPG.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using crop, you must check: delete cropped pixels. It preserves your background layer.

If you leave it unchecked, the PS will make your layer a Layer0 instead of Background. So the PS will never save it using File>>Sive.

See the picture below.

[image]